# How do I set a custom time frame for this study, rather than the system's default regular session timeframe?

Tags: pine-script

Edit: A quick note to clarify what I'm after:  I want to load three specific data points into three variables. I'd like to be able to pull the closing price of any symbol for a specific time, like 4:15 PM EST.  I'd also like to find the high and low price from within a custom time range, like 4:30 PM EST yesterday to 4:15 PM EST today.  Ideally, I shouldn't have to wait until market open the following day for the chart to update. - end of note/edit

I'm writing a script to draw out the pivot points as per John Carter's book, Mastering the trade, and I've got it working, except for one important detail, I'm not using the correct time-frame, which is ruining the current data.  So I need to get it right.  I've prepared a snippet of the code that shows the general idea, so I don't have to spam a couple hundred lines of rough-draft code here.

The TL:DR code just shows what I'm currently using, and what I want to do which is commented out, as that doesn't work and creates a study error.

The longer version will actually draw a line on your chart if you want to copy/paste something semi-functional into Tradingview to see what's going on.  All it's doing is drawing the close price from the previous session, I left out all the variables and math for the actual script as it's unnecessarily complicating to solve this particular issue.

TL:DR code

```
timeResolution = input("D", type=input.resolution)
//timeResolution = input("1630-1615:1234567", type=input.resolution)
priceClose = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeResolution, close[1], lookahead=true)
```

The longer code

```
//@version=4

study("What am I doing?", overlay=true)

//declaring color variables
var color gray = #D1D4DC

//declaring a line variable
var line closeLine = na

//declaring a label variable
var line closeLabel = na

//Fetching Price Data
timeResolution = input("D", type=input.resolution)
//timeResolution = input("1630-1615:1234567", type=input.resolution)
priceClose = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeResolution, close[1], lookahead=true)

if priceClose[1] != priceClose
    line.set_x2(closeLine, bar_index)
    
    //This stops the line from drawing over the next line
    line.set_extend(closeLine, extend.none)
    
    //This draws the line
    closeLine := line.new(bar_index, priceClose, bar_index, priceClose, extend=extend.right, color = gray)


if not na(closeLine) and line.get_x2(closeLine) != bar_index

    //This sets the beginning of the line to the left
    line.set_x2(closeLine, bar_index)
```

Edit:  Here's a screen grab of an example of what I'm trying to fetch, and the time-frame involved  This is a chart of SPY from today's session, including the pre-market session, the after-hours session from Friday, and today's after-hours session so far.  I placed blue vertical bars to indicate the in and out points for the time frame I want, I want the high and low from anywhere in this time-frame, and the close for the end of the time-frame, which is in the after-hours session.

Edit 2: I got the times reversed in the photo, the 16:30 bar should be 16:15 on the one side, and opposite on the other.  No matter, it's still the same general idea.

[image: Example Time-frame range I'm after]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here

https://uk.tradingview.com/script/gOuxEE0n-High-Low-Close-V2/

Apply it to your chart and see if it gives you the output you are after.

EST 16:15 is equal to UTC 20:15.

Pine script uses UTC so I have set the close to 20:15 and the others to suit.

Comment: No, I want to gather high, low and close from the time frame between, for example, the after hours session beginning at 1630, and collecting 15 minutes short of a full 24 hours, the following day at 16:15.  So for example, I might want the data starting from the Friday session starting at 1630, and the collection the premarket on Monday, all of the regular session, and the first 15 minutes of the after hours session that Monday.

Comment: I don't understand how your code is pulling the close data from that time-frame, it's a bit over my head.  How would I also get the high and low?

Comment: What time period are you after the high low to and from? What symbols do you use this on?

Comment: Using it on SPY right now, and I want the High, Low and Close from 16:30 to 16:15, which covers the afternoon session on one day(minus 30 minutes), the morning session and the regular session the next day plus 15 minutes of that second day afternoon session.

Comment: I added a photo and more explanation in the original post.

Comment: I have started to put some code together but could you confirm what the Symbol Name is (AMEX:SPY or CAPITOLCOM:SPY / BMV:SPY etc). I ask as Timezone/session period can affect the code

Comment: NYSE, it's the S&P 500 SPDR ETF.  But the times should ideally be adjustable so I can share it with others who might want to trade futures, but will need a different time window.

Comment: Hrm, no.  That's a lot of complicated charting and line drawing and text and I don't want any of that.  I just want specific data points at specific times.  I want the close at 4:15PM EST, I want the lows and highs from the time period from 4:30 yesterday, to 4:15 today, including all after hours sessions, and that close price comes from the after hours session.  I just need to know how to access those specific data points so I can assign them to variables, and let the math in my indicator do it's thing.  I already have a working indicator coded, I'm just entering those values manually now.

Comment: I think what would help me (rather than guessing or trying to work out time differences) is that you. 1. Go to the Symbol name (top right) click on the three dots and then Symbol Info (upload a picture of that information. 2. Change you Trading View time to UTC 0000 and then draw a lines and use the text tool to the areas you are interested in. 
I am just a bit confused and think if you do the above it will assist.

Comment: You're trying to do too much, the symbol is irrelevant, it should work with any symbol.  I don't need anything that draws anything on a chart, I already know how to do that.  I just need three specific data points.  That's it.  I just don't know how to get the specific data points I want loaded into a variable I can use.  The code you initially supplied, and seem to have since removed,  looked like it was on the right track, I just didn't understand how it worked.  I couldn't figure out how to adapt it to my needs.  I'll update my original question to clarify this